# Sort Order in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

Can I change the default sort order in a SQL server database so that nulls and zero length strings are displayed last.

Its SQL Server 2000

I stress, I want to change the *default* order for all queries, if possible

Answer (score 5):

You can do almost any sort using a `case` in an `order by`.  Here's the `null` columns first, then the empty strings, and the rest ordered on col1 and col3:

```
select  *
from    YourTable
order by
        case when col1 is null then 1
             when col1 = '' then 2
             else 3
        end
,       col2
,       col3 desc
```

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot do that: Without ORDER BY, there is no default sort order. This is a very common question, so I wrote a canned answer: [Without ORDER BY, there is no default sort order](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx)

Comment: +1 I believe this is the only answer so far that *really* adresses the question. OP asks specificly about the *default* sort order (which doesn't exist)

Comment: I suspect this isn't what they mean though. They would like to be able to do `order by x` and have nulls and empty strings at the end rather than the beginning.

Comment: @Martin : I can confirm you are correct : that that is eaxctly what they mean. Maybe its the collation sequence I need to change.

Answer (score 1):

add a dummy newcolumn = (length(targetcolumn)>0), and sort by this first.