# Does a SELECT statement select the data in the same order everytime?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a table `Emp` with `emp_id`, `emp_name`. I insert 3 entries in the table - `(1,A)  (2,B)  (3,C)`.

I do not create any primary key nor add any indexes.

Now, when I run a `select * statement`, will the data be displayed as `(1,A),(2,B),(3,C)` every time or is there a possibility for the output to be `(2,B), (1,A), (3,C)` or in other variations.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3574284/330315 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/36077399/330315

Comment: Actually, in this case - three rows, inserted in this order, no CI, no NCIs, no updates/deletes, no rebuilds etc - these rows will be returned in this order. But of course, any schema or data or engine change could break it, so an ORDER BY is required. BTW, I don't understand how come this question got upvoted, being answered so many time already??

Answer (score 3):

The data can be displayed in **any** order, by a key, index, or even randomly .

The only way to "force" and guarantee the data will be displayed in the same order every time, is to use the `ORDER BY` clause and force the optimizer to select the data in the order you specifically asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "ORDER BY" clause to guarantee order. Otherwise it's up to db engine, configuration and/or schema.

Read the following [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236352/default-row-order-in-select-query-sql-server-2008-vs-sql-2012), to get a more detailed reason.